# How to store customfields from atlassian's Json Response e.g.(customfield_10020) which is coming dynamic everytime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

Here is the response I am getting from Api which is dynamic as shown in the picture. I got the value in `customfield_10011` key. In the other object down I am getting value in `customfield_10014` key. Now how should I loop it and save data in c#?

[image: ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/MufaD.png]

Comment: Why not create a model that matches the JSON?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro, I already tried it but my key changes from development URL and Live URL. So I wanted it to set it from appsetting.JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Json.Net it is simple enough to serialize it to Dynamic.

```
dynamic myDynamicJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'environment': null, 'customfield_10027': "Multi Sensor Updated" }");

string customfield10027 = myDynamicJson.customfield_10027;
```

**Edit**

To get the field name from config I would rather go for the custom resolver method. But in case you can't:

```
dynamic myDynamicJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'environment': null, 'customfield_10027': 'Multi Sensor Updated' }");
string myFieldNameFromConfig = "customfield_100273";

string result = myDynamicJson[myFieldNameFromConfig];
```

Comment: in development mode it's loading into customfield_10027, but in live mode it's loading into customfield_10018. Now I want to set these in appsetting.json and consume from there.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Jira API.

If you are 100% sure that those custom properties will not change then for sure go the dynamic route.

I have been integrating with multiple Jira instances and they had different custom fields for the same property, so a more fluent mapping is preferred, because it can be done dynamically from some configuration.

This can be achieved with a `CustomContractResolver` of `JsonConvert`.

Example:

```
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JiraIssuePayload>(str, new JsonSerializerSettings()
 {
     ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(new Dictionary<string, string>
     {
         {"EpicName", "customfield_10011" },
         {"Epic", "customfield_10012" }, // these could come from some configuration object
     });
 }
```

What is done here is that you tell `JsonConvert` to deserialize `customfield_10011` to the property `EpicName` of your type (and `Epic` for the other one).

Comment: in development mode it's loading into customfield_10027, but in live mode it's loading into customfield_10018. Now I want to set these in appsetting.json and consume from there.

Comment: @Vishvjitshinde then the way I described it is the way to do it.